# load child objects in EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a method in my generic repository:

```
public IQueryable<T> Query<T>() where T : class, IEntity
{
   return _context.Set<T>();
}
```

This is method for getting user:

```
public User GetUser(string email)
{
   return _repository.Query<User>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);
}
```

Finally, I put the user to session:

```
AppSession.CurrentUser = UserService.GetUser(email);
```

In my action I need to get the current user and get collection of objects `Notifications` (one-to-many):

```
AppSession.CurrentUser.Notifications.OfType<EmailNotification>().FirstOrDefault();
```

But, here I get the error:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

I know that `Notifications` not loaded when I getting `User` from DB.
 How to say EF to load `Notifications` objects?  I know about `Include`, but I cannot use it in `GetUser` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the first HttpRequest ends after looking up your `CurrentUser` object, your `_repository` reference that the `CurrentUser` is expecting for additional lookups like EmailNotifications isn't available.

The exception is thrown because `CurrentUser` doesn't have the original object context, so you either have to attach the CurrentUser object to the new objectContext that your `_repository` is using, or use the easier solution of simply reloading the user through the new context that was created for your current request in the repository.

Before attempting to find the notifications in your action, add the following line:

```
AppSession.CurrentUser = UserService.GetUser(AppSession.CurrentUser.Email);
AppSession.CurrentUser.Notifications.OfType<EmailNotification>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Ryan [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15404053/33116) it is due to the fact that the object context is not available to lazy load in the associated notifications.

What I'd suggest is turn off lazy loading (if possible) as can cause lots of issues later and then do something like ...

```
var user = UserService.GetUser(AppSession.CurrentUser.Email);
user.Notifications = NotificationService.GetUserNotifications(user.Id /* or another identifier */);
AppSession.CurrentUser = user;
```

To do this you will require a new NotificationService, this can load (as suggested above) but also handle the execution of notifications (sending emails etc).

You should now have the notifications for that user in your Application session cache.

HTH